# FosUserBundle routes do not load the correct User Entity

Tags: php, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I use the following with success all over my site.

```
{{ app.user.getId }}
```

I also have my own functions because I have extended the Fos User Entity base class. So I can use this too.

```
{{ app.user.getMyThing }}
```

But when loading the FosUserBundle routes these custom functions fail. For example on the Edit Profile route the following just returns a blank string

```
{{ app.user.getMyThing }}
```

But on my own routes it works correctly.

The FosUserBundle therefore, I think, is loading its own Entity and not my extended Entity.

How can I get my User Entity from within the templates I have overridden, for example the Edit Profile view.

Comment: Take a look at creating a [twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html).  I've used it in very similar circumstances.

Comment: Did you set user_class properly? https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-5-configure-the-fosuserbundle . `app.user` should be getting current user from security token and it shouldn't matter which route you're on.

Comment: Yes Igor that is set. geoB, that seems a really odd solution. Write a whole Twig extension just to get something that should already be there?

Answer (score 0):

If you extend FOSUser and want to override something, you have to create your own Controller and your own views (that extends FOSUSer surely) so in the FOSUser level (the down level) your entity is invisible because FOSUser is using his own model.

In the Other hand every think will work fine at your level (your own routes) because You are using your own entity (that extends FOSUser one). So if you would override FOSUser to point at your entity you need override the hole bundle, reed this doc [How to Use Bundle Inheritance to Override Parts of a Bundle](http://symfony.com/en/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html)

Comment: I have overridden the bundle already. The place where I am trying to access to user is in a template I have overridden.

Comment: What you get if you var_dump($user) in the editAction of ProfileController!!

Comment: `$user = $this->getUser();` in my ProfileController that overrides The FOS one gives me my Entity.

Comment: I dont get the error , it feels like everything is fine. So pass your user to the view and show your attribute. Im just thinking that you messed to generate entities for your entity ???

Comment: Why do I need to assign the user in the controller? I should be able to use app.user